# How to sum several bracket numbers of a single cell with Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

right now i have this cell:

[EXAMPLE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC5g6.png)

and I want a formula to sum up only the numbers inside the brackets. For example

A2: 8(96),11(4),13(24) THEREFORE THE SUM WILL BE 124

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/sum-multiple-numbers-in-parentheses.1141333/

Another option is to copy and split the cell into multiple cells.